# VS Code не работают пользовательские сниппеты вместе с встроенными emmet снипетами

Tags: visual-studio-code, scss

раньше всё работало, но не знаю почему когда именно в настройках самого элемента пишешь префикс снипета он не отображается а просто в самом файле scss всё работает, если что расширение для scss в самих снипетах есть, т.е. фрагменты кода Emmet перекрывают пользовательские фрагменты и мне надо чтобы пользовательские снипеты всегда отображались первые в списке сокращений

[image: снипеты работают]

[image: Сниппеты не отображаются]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0):

Откройте настройки (Ctrl+Shift+P), найдите Emmet в пункте Extensions(Расширения), в нём пункт Show Expanded Abbreviation нужно установить "never".